# Data Structure Field in a DB

Tags: database

I have some items that are unique by their Item_ID. Each set of items combined create a new item which has a "price" value.

For instance, Item numbers: 1, 5, 7 has a price value of $10.00 and item numbers: 1, 10, 2 has  a price value of $20.00

I want to store the price values in a database and upon request to pull the correct information. The item numbers themselves are stored in a C# set - where order is not important. When querying, item numbers: 1, 5, 7 and 1, 7, 5 we should retrieve the same value from the DB.

I was thinking of storing the values in a string field but that will create a problem when the order of the items is not the same. I also thought about XML - but how will I query the DB letting it know order of child notes is not important.

Need help!

Thanks!

Comment: is number 1 belongs to both the set? 10$ and 20$?

Comment: Yes, each number can appear in different sets. Moreover, the size of each set is not the same.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe save it with attribute defined by sum and multiplication of this items?

{1,2,7}, {7,2,1} - 10 14 30$

Comment: But then 1,2,7 and 3,7 have the same value.

Comment: Maybe if we include multiplication & sum in it?

Comment: Yes, it seems it must work, if you include multiplication, but multiplication can give big value.

Comment: Does anybody know if this will work? I'm not really a math genius but can different sets have the same multiplication and sum?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new table called Item_Groups and assign a group id for a group of items

**Item_Groups**

```
Group_ID | Item_ID
1 | 1
1 | 5
1 | 7
2 | 1
2 | 2
2 | 10
```

**Item_Group_Price** will be separate table to assign price to a group

```
Group_ID | Price
1 | 10$
1 | 20$
```

When you have items 1,5,7, check the first table to know the Group ID and then use this Group ID and get the price from the second table.

Comment: Its a possibility but searching this table will cause multiple queries. I find it hard to believe that there is no better way to achieve this.